# React js material ui initial value equal to ""

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a select field, with topics, the topics are for example the following:

- name -> label

---

1. "" -> /
2. "logs" -> /logs
3. "exec" -> /exec

I would like to make sure to start the topic as a value with the name equal to "" and the label "/", that is the first one, are values ​​that I take from the db so I can't make changes.

Can you help me out?

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-wood-lzbhk)

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { TextField, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    pubtopic: "",
    subscriptions: [
      {
        name: "",
        label: "/"
      },
      {
        name: "exec",
        label: "/exec"
      },
      {
        name: "log",
        label: "/log"
      }
    ]
  });

  const { pubtopic, subscriptions } = state;

  const onChange = name => ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        id="pubtopic"
        select
        label="Topic"
        placeholder="Topic"
        variant="outlined"
        value={pubtopic}
        onChange={onChange("pubtopic")}
        size="small"
        fullWidth
      >
        {subscriptions.map((el, key) => (
          <MenuItem key={key} value={el.name}>
            {el.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
      pubtopic: {pubtopic}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two additions for this to work decently:

- You need to set the [Select prop](https://material-ui.com/api/select/#props) `displayEmpty` to `true` so that it will treat an empty string value as something that it should still try to display instead of treating it as meaning that nothing is selected.
- You need to set the [InputLabel prop](https://material-ui.com/api/input-label/#props) `shrink` to `true`, so that even when the current value of the `TextField` is empty string it will still move the label up rather than presenting it over the top of the "/" option.

Below is a working example based on your sandbox:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { TextField, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    pubtopic: "",
    subscriptions: [
      {
        name: "",
        label: "/"
      },
      {
        name: "exec",
        label: "/exec"
      },
      {
        name: "log",
        label: "/log"
      }
    ]
  });

  const { pubtopic, subscriptions } = state;

  const onChange = name => ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        id="pubtopic"
        select
        label="Topic"
        variant="outlined"
        value={pubtopic}
        onChange={onChange("pubtopic")}
        size="small"
        fullWidth
        SelectProps={{ displayEmpty: true }}
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
      >
        {subscriptions.map((el, key) => (
          <MenuItem key={key} value={el.name}>
            {el.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
      pubtopic: {pubtopic}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Select with empty value as an option]